# Where to find a Python facial landmark detection library that is trained on a dataset with commercial use permissions?

Tags: python, facial-recognition

I am looking for some Python library (or open-source project) that detects facial landmarks in real-time from a webcam, similarly to how dlib 68 point facial landmark detector works. Ideally, free but I am willing to pay up to 100$, if it is at least as good as dlib.

While dlib landmark detector almost fully satisfies my needs (except that I would also like to have eye pupils marked), however, dlib's facial landmark detection algorithm was trained on iBug-300W dataset, and that is not meant for commercial use.

Actually, I don't need all 68 points, I need only corners of the mouth, lip centers, pupils and eyelids to be able to capture basic facial expressions real-time from a webcamera.

I have found also a paid library, but the price is about 15,000$ yearly, which is way too high for an indie developer.

Comment: Have you considered creating your own  dataset for dlib with a less restrictive licence (http://dlib.net/train_shape_predictor_ex.cpp.html)? Or possibly asking the current authors if they have a commercial licence available and what it would cost?

Comment: @SteveBarnes   As I found out, the owner of the dlib's dataset is Imperial College London and they have strictly specified that commercial use is not allowed. So, I highly doubt they would add any exclusions for me. Creating my own dataset is an option, however, it might take ages for me to learn ML and to create a good dataset and do the training. I hoped that someone has already done that and could sell me their trained model for dlib.

Comment: It might be worth expanding your question, _or asking another_, to include the availability of a commercial use allowed data set for dlib.